# Changing property names in Google application engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is there any way to alter the Property names in the Google application engine for a Kind, or in other words is there a way to alter the column names of a table in Google application Engine (though it follows a different way to handle the data)? I am using python.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refactoring on Google AppEngine involves you having to either modify all of the records in your datastore as you make the change, or write the code so that it will still read the old value if the new value doesn't exist.

Removing a column from the datastore is possible but not easy. More information can be found [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Matthew, my requirement is actually to rename a property keeping the data intact. For e.g. if there is a kind Employee, with a property like name.. I would like to rename it as employee_name, keeping all the records in it intact.

Comment: I think that the only way to do this would be to create a new field, save the data for all of your objects and then get rid of the old field.